# How can I sort the output from an awk script?

Tags: bash, sorting, unix, awk

When I run check script, I get the o/p as below,

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 noper sbcprd 9175 Aug 6 03:36 opLogDir    
-rw-rw-r-- 1 soper sbcprd 9104 Aug 6 03:04 opLogDir    
-rw-rw-r-- 1 moper sbcprd 9561 Aug 6 02:18 opLogDir    
-rw-rw-r-- 1 woper sbcprd 9561 Aug 6 05:06 opLogDir    
-rw-rw-r-- 1 boper sbcprd 9834 Aug 6 03:34 opLogDir    
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xoper sbcprd 9873 Aug 6 00:50 opLogDir
-rw-rw-r-- 1 doper sbcprd 9479 Aug 6 04:12 opLogDir
```

Now I can select data from it and sort using:

```
check | awk '{print $3,$8,$6,$7}'| sort
```

and get the o/p as below,

```
boper 03:34 Aug 6
doper 04:12 Aug 6
moper 02:18 Aug 6
noper 03:36 Aug 6
soper 03:04 Aug 6
woper 05:06 Aug 6
xoper 00:50 Aug 6
```

It sorts the o/p by column #1.

How can I sort the o/p according to the timings (column #2)?

Comment: You should mention, if the date could be different or not? In your example they are all `Aug 6`. IMO, this would be important information for solutions.

Comment: What is `check` doing? Because if it is just `ls`, you better rely on its options instead of parsing its output. For example, `ls -lt` will sort based on modification-time.

Comment: Your question subject ie very misleading - you're asking how to sort text by the 2nd column, not how to sort using awk. The fact the text was generated from an awk script is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Note that after about 6 months, `ls -l` changes the date format from `MMM dd HH:MM` to `MMM dd YYYY`.  This won't matter if you're only dealing with today's files, but it could become a problem if you're not careful.

Comment: @Kent, date is always current date. Only timings in column #2 vary.

Comment: @EdMorton 
check is not a command it is just short script i've written.
my apologies for misleading.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, I did not know that. Can you tell me when it exactly changes(name of the months)?

Comment: I didn't ask anything about the `check` script. So far I have no idea what it is you're actually trying to do and so don't know how to help you. Do you need help sorting info about files? Or sorting some plain text by a specific field? Or something else?

Comment: The POSIX specification for [`ls`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html) says (in part): _The `<date and time>` field shall contain the appropriate date and timestamp of when the file was last modified. In the POSIX locale, the field shall be the equivalent of the output of the following date command:

`date "+%b %e %H:%M"`

if the file has been modified in the last six months, or:

`date "+%b %e %Y"`

(… ) if the file has not been modified in the last six months or if the modification date is in the future, …_  It isn't more precise about what 'six months' means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `sort` command. `sort -k 2`

Although, given this looks like `ls` output, you could probably change `check` to have `ls -lt` to sort by timestamp instead.

If you need something more extensive (e.g. that includes date and time based sorting) then it's harder - you'll need to use something that can parse the timestamp into a unix time.

E.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece; 

my $year = Time::Piece->localtime -> year;

for ( <DATA> ) {
     my ( $mon, $day, $time ) = (split)[5,6,7];
     my $timestamp = Time::Piece->strptime("$mon $day $time $year", '%b %d %H:%M %Y');
     print $timestamp -> epoch,"\n";
}

__DATA__
-rw-rw-r-- 1 noper sbcprd 9175 Aug 6 03:36 opLogDir    
-rw-rw-r-- 1 soper sbcprd 9104 Aug 6 03:04 opLogDir    
-rw-rw-r-- 1 moper sbcprd 9561 Aug 6 02:18 opLogDir    
-rw-rw-r-- 1 woper sbcprd 9561 Aug 6 05:06 opLogDir    
-rw-rw-r-- 1 boper sbcprd 9834 Aug 6 03:34 opLogDir    
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xoper sbcprd 9873 Aug 6 00:50 opLogDir
-rw-rw-r-- 1 doper sbcprd 9479 Aug 6 04:12 opLogDir
```

Or with the sorting logic built int:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece; 

my $year = Time::Piece->localtime -> year;

sub sort_by_timestamp {
    my ( $amon, $aday, $atime ) = (split( " ", $a ))[5,6,7];
    my ( $bmon, $bday, $btime ) = (split( " ", $b ))[5,6,7];
    my $at = Time::Piece->strptime("$amon $aday $atime $year", '%b %d %H:%M %Y');
    my $bt = Time::Piece->strptime("$bmon $bday $btime $year", '%b %d %H:%M %Y');

    return $at <=> $bt;
}


print sort { sort_by_timestamp } <DATA>;

__DATA__
-rw-rw-r-- 1 noper sbcprd 9175 Aug 6 03:36 opLogDir    
-rw-rw-r-- 1 soper sbcprd 9104 Aug 6 03:04 opLogDir    
-rw-rw-r-- 1 moper sbcprd 9561 Aug 6 02:18 opLogDir    
-rw-rw-r-- 1 woper sbcprd 9561 Aug 6 05:06 opLogDir    
-rw-rw-r-- 1 boper sbcprd 9834 Aug 6 03:34 opLogDir    
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xoper sbcprd 9873 Aug 6 00:50 opLogDir
-rw-rw-r-- 1 doper sbcprd 9479 Aug 6 04:12 opLogDir
```

Note - for obvious reasons, this won't work very well when you span a year.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know `-k` option, you can still do it by putting `$8` at the first place：

```
awk '{print $8,$3,$6,$7}'
```